# Confidence intervals of proportions for clustered data

Tags: confidence-interval, multilevel-analysis, proportion, bugs

I am trying to compute the proportion of "yes"'s in data that is clustered (participants within cities). If I ignore the cities, I get very nice and narrow confidence intervals. If I compute the proportions within each city, I get rather wide confidence intervals. When I try to fit a "multilevel model" in WinBUGS through logistic regression[1], I get a *very* wide confidence interval...

How should I interpret these results, and what is the best way to go about it?

[1] This is my WinBUGS code for the "multilevel" case:

```
model{
for (i in 1:3215){
    x[i] ~ dbern(theta[city[i]])
}

for (j in 1:142){
    logit(theta[j]) <- z[j]
    z[j] ~ dnorm(mu, tau)
}



mu ~ dnorm(0, 0.00001)
tau <- 1/(sigma * sigma)
sigma ~ dunif(0, 10000)
y ~ dnorm(mu, tau)
p <- exp(y)/(1+exp(y))   # the quantity of interest, overall proportion of "yes"'s
}
```